# Close SQL connections cleanly when connection dropped

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, event-handling

Just wondering if there is a way that I can close all SQL connections and commands in the cleanest possible way when a connection is lost in VB.NET (can also be in C#.NET).

What I'm trying to achieve:

Using the System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkAvailabilityChanged event, I'm monitoring whether the connection has been lost. If it has been lost, I'm disabling all user input - works great. Network comes back on, UI is enabled. *(thumbs up)*

Now, however, comes my predicament. If an SQL query is executing before the connection drops and then the network is lost, then the query returns a null value as expected, however if that was mid population of datatables/fields, then I get NullReferenceExceptions.

My question is:

Is there anyway to cleanly exit a sub **after** the connection has dropped? I've tried Application.ExitThread, but that doesn't seem to quite cut it. Do I need to put dropped connection handlers within my objects, so that when the connection is dropped, the respective object won't return or try to assign null data?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Not asking for plain code, need explanations if at all possible. Cheers.

Comment: If a query/object is supposed to return data, or write data to the database, and it cannot fulfill that purpose, then throw an exception. (You're dealing with an exceptional situation, your object cannot do what it is meant to do.)

Then let the calling code deal with these exceptions.

Comment: That makes sense, of course. This would then mean however that the majority of the code will be wrapped in try-catch statements. I guess this is the only plausible way around it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the "using" best practice, like:

```
Using cn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    ...
End Using
```

Then the compiler will generate code that cleans up the connection when an exception is thrown.

Comment: I do that within the SQL class, they are all contained in using statements. I guess my question was a little unclear - when I am within a sub that has already called a function to return, say, a datatable, how would I exit that sub if my network were to drop during the execution of the query? I guess stakx's response to wrap it in a try-catch and throw an exception makes the most sense. I do appreciate your response though. Cheers.